# Parse Bluetooth ble.write json string on Arduino

Tags: c++, json, arduino

I am attempting to parse a JSON string coming into the Arduino from my phone. I am fairly new to C++ and these libraries so I am having some issues. Below is the code I have so far. Everything works except for the part where I am trying to set json[] to the value coming from the phone. It is a valid JSON and is returned to the console shown below.

> Error: initializer fails to determine size of 'json'

JSON Received from phone:

```
{"SSID":"Sample","PSK":"test","TOKEN":"1234","HOSTNAME":"secondarycontroller"}
```

ESP32 Code:

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();


      if(value.length() > 0) {

        StaticJsonDocument<800> doc;
        char json[] = value;
        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json);
        if (error) {
          Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
          Serial.println(error.c_str());
          return;
        }

        Serial.println(doc["SSID"]);
        Serial.println(doc["PSK"]);
        Serial.println(doc["HOSTNAME"]);
        Serial.println(doc["TOKEN"]);


        Serial.println("*********");
        Serial.print("New value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
          Serial.print(value[i]);

        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("*********");
      }
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("1- Download and install an BLE scanner app in your phone");
  Serial.println("2- Scan for BLE devices in the app");
  Serial.println("3- Connect to MyESP32");
  Serial.println("4- Go to CUSTOM CHARACTERISTIC in CUSTOM SERVICE and write something");
  Serial.println("5- See the magic =)");

  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World");
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: initializer fails to determine size of 'json'

Comment: Sorry not familiar with this library actually working - I tend to read those jsons in as text strings and then strip out the bit I'm looking for. Inelegant but it works.

Comment: I am getting close creating a function myself as you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of desrializeJson()](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/deserializejson/), the second input argument accepts `char*` with zero-copy; and, `const char*` or `const std::string&` with duplication.

Prototypes in the documentation (only the relevant ones):

```
// writable input => zero-copy
DeserializationError deserializeJson(JsonDocument& doc, char* input);
DeserializationError deserializeJson(JsonDocument& doc, char* input, size_t inputSize);

// read-only input => duplication
DeserializationError deserializeJson(JsonDocument& doc, const char* input);
DeserializationError deserializeJson(JsonDocument& doc, const char* input, size_t inputSize);
// ...
DeserializationError deserializeJson(JsonDocument& doc, const std::string& input);
```

Observe the second argument in the above prototypes!

---

So, the following lines:

```
char json[] = value;
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json);
```

would be:

```
const char* json = value.c_str();
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json);
```

Or, directly pass `value` like this:

```
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, value);
```

That should solve your problem.

---

The error you're getting is about this line:

```
char json[] = value;
//       ^^
```

The size of the `char` array is missing here. You must specify the size of the static array in this context. Plus, `value` is not directly convertible in this case.

---

Tip:

Use [std::string::empty()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) in the following case:

```
if(value.length() > 0)
```

i.e.

```
if( !value.empty() )
```

It's more readable and expressive!

Comment: This fixes the value issue but the doc does not return its values. Serial.println(doc["SSID"]); results in the following error.call of overloaded 'println(ArduinoJson6141_0000010::enable_if<true, ArduinoJson6141_0000010::MemberProxy<ArduinoJson6141_0000010::JsonDocument&, const char*> >::type)' is ambiguous

Comment: @James: This should solve your problem: https://arduinojson.org/v6/error/call-of-overloaded-println-is-ambiguous/. You ought to refer to the documentation as much as you can especially before using any API. That would speed up your development.